# How to define a do-nothing event?

Tags: vimscript

As title. I want to define an event via `autocmd User MyEvent ...`. Then when some internal state of my plugin is reached, I will trigger the event with `doautocmd User MyEvent`. So, how to write the part `...`?

Comment: `autocmd User MyEvent` does not define an event; it defines an autocommand to react to that event. However, there is a no-op command (`:`).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: I read the answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22784667/5290519), which said it did define the event. So how to define an event exactly?

Comment: That answer is imprecise: there is no code that defines a User event. You simply invoke it when you wish, and autocommands established to react will fire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no API for defining custom events. What you define are autocommands that are meant to be executed explicitly. Executing those autocommands explicitly is the closest you can get from having custom events.

In their simplest form, autocommands look like this:

```
autocmd <event> <pattern> <command>
```

where:

- `<event>` is the event that triggers the autocommand,
- `<pattern>` is matched against the value of the event,
- `<command>` is whatever you want to happen if `<pattern>` matches.

The `User` event can be understood as a generic event which is never triggered automatically by Vim. Instead, `User` autocommands are executed explicitly with `:help :doautocmd` and passed an arbitrary value. You *mimic* custom events, you don't "define" them.

Now, a `User` autocommand is defined the same way other autocommands are:

```
autocmd User MyThing echo 'foo'
```

where:

- `User` is your `<event>`,
- `MyThing` is your `<pattern>`,
- and `echo 'foo'` is your `<command>`.

You would then execute that autocommand explicitly:

```
:doautocmd User MyThing
foo
```

where:

- `User` is the dummy event you are triggering,
- `MyThing` is its value.

Because you have defined a `User` autocommand with the pattern `MyThing` and you are triggering it with the value `MyThing`, the pattern matches the value and the command is executed.

--- EDIT ---

I don't use Neovim so I have no idea what the API you are mentioning in the comments does. If I were in your shoes, I would "probe" it with something like:

```
autocmd User * echomsg 'the value is ' .. expand('<amatch>')
```

which should echo the value of the event:

```
(do something with that API)
the value is foobar
```

which would then help me decide what pattern to use for my `User` autocommand:

```
autocmd User foobar ...
```

See `:help <amatch>`.

--- EDIT #2 ---

The value is a *string*. It is a file name for many events but not all of them (`:help ColorScheme` comes to mind) so the `<pattern>` can be any pattern that matches the particular value that comes with a particular event.

For a `User` event, it is up to the *user* to decide what value to send, how to match against it, and what to do with it. The following example shows the extent of what one can do with `:help User`. It is a bit contrived but it is all I could come up on the spot.

1. Define an autocommand that evaluates the value and uses it to move the cursor:

   ```
   augroup MyAutocommands
       autocmd!
       autocmd User \[*\] call expand('<amatch>')->eval()->cursor()
   augroup END
   ```
2. Trigger the autocommand with a list of coordinates as value:

   ```
   let myValue = [3, 20]->string()
   :execute 'doautocmd User ' .. myValue
   ```

   [image: au]
3. Note the pattern `\[*\]`. It is a bit simplistic but it is useful for demonstrating how the whole thing works. If you do something like:

   ```
   :doautocmd User foobar
   ```

   then Vim will will say:

   ```
   No matching autocommands for: User foobar
   ```

   Another approach would be to use `*` as pattern and call a function where you can use a fancy regular expression to decide if the value matches or not.

One could imagine passing a serialized dictionary, the same way we use JSON, or any arbitrary syntax. It just has to be a string.

Comment: Well, this is very clear now. But say there is an official neovim API(`vim.diagnostic.open_float`) that accepts `close_events`. Then in this case if I add `User` to the list/table, then what `<pattern>` should I use in my plugin to make sure that the close event of that API will be triggered?

Comment: @job_start, see my edit.

Comment: Isn't that `<pattern>` should be a file pattern, e.g `*.c`? Why you said it can be any value.

Comment: @job_start, see my edit.

Comment: In neovim, run `:h au` gives `:au[tocmd] [group] {event} {aupat} [++once] [++nested] {cmd}`, where it is called `{aupat}`. And if you further run `:h aupat` you will see they describing things as `The file pattern {aupat} ...`. This is the cause of my confusion: They implicitly mean `{aupat}` is a file-path. I found nowhere mentioning `{aupat}` can be any string.

Comment: But the example(`:help ColorScheme`) you pointed out in your edit 2 did make me believe your argument is correct: it can be any string.

Comment: Note also `:h v:event`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no code that defines a `User` event. You simply invoke it when you wish, and autocommands established to react will fire.

Note the caveat under `:help doautocmd` about `<nomodeline>`, and under `:help User` about what happens when no autocommands are "subscribed" to the event.

Comment: I still don't know how to achieve what I want vim to do.

Comment: Write your code, and have it run `doautocmd User MyEvent` as needed (possibly guarded by an `exists` check as mentioned in `:help User`). That's it.

Comment: In neovim there is an API `vim diagnostic.open_float(...)` where I can pass a lua table that contains a key `close_events`, which is lua table containing some built-in events. Now what I want to do is to add my custom event to the table/list but it caused some error.

Comment: @job_start That isn’t what the question asks… but it is interesting. I would reach out to neovim devs.

Comment: `:help User` doesn't explain what will happen when no autocmd are subscribed to the event. (I'm using neovim.)