# How to define a User autocmd event based on a command being executed?

Tags: autocmd

I am struggling in using doautocmd to mimic a user-defined event.
The event I am trying to mimic is "*After :MyCommand has been executed*"

I am trying to achieve that goal with the following snippet

```
command MyCommand :echom 'bar'

augroup TEST
    autocmd!
    autocmd User MyCommand :echom 'foo'
augroup END
doautocmd User MyCommand
```

but when I run `:MyCommand` only `'bar'` is echoed.

What I would expect is to echo `'bar'` and then echo `'foo'` every time `:MyCommand` is executed.

Comment: Include either `echom 'foo'` or `doautocmd User MyCommand` into `:MyCommand`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what is the difference between the two other than in one you use autocmd and in the other you don't, i.e. what is the utility of `doautocmd`? Perhaps this example is too simplistic to appreciate its usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include either `echom 'foo'` or `doautocmd User MyCommand` into the RHS of `MyCommand`:

```
command MyCommand :echom 'bar' | echom 'foo'
```

or:

```
command MyCommand :echom 'bar' | doautocmd User MyCommand
```

You would do the former if all you really need is `foo` to be echoed when you do `:MyCommand`. Simple needs, simple means.

You would do the latter if…

- you want that extra functionality defined elsewhere than in `MyCommand`,
- you want it to be usable in other contexts than `MyCommand`,
- it is too involved for a one-liner,
- you don't want things to break if it is not implemented.

> what is the utility of `doautocmd`?

`:help :doautocmd` is the closest Vim has to the ability of emitting custom events.

See [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/38935/54) for a somewhat deeper explanation of `:doautocmd`.

Comment: Thanks. I already read both, but I have to think a bit more on it. For example, what if we replace echom 'foo' with call MyFunction() ? That should cover all the three bullet points you wrote.

Comment: Yes, and with a bit of checking it would also cover a fourth that I forgot: not break if the extra functionality is not implemented. Choosing one or the other is more a question of mental model, I guess. Events or callbacks.

Comment: Perfect. Now it’s clear. Thanks.